# Here is UserApp.xaml file, while project running the program, XamlParseException is summoned, and program doesn't compile fully

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, xamlparseexception

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to get this code working smoothly, as shown in a C# WPF tutorial for creating a registration menu (which is now three years old; hopefully, it's still relevant). I'm struggling with handling an exception and would appreciate some guidance.

The issue revolves around a detailed exception, "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException," causing the program to halt in XamlReader.cs with an error as follows:

Here's the full exception stack:
`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
HResult=0x80131501
Message="Calling a constructor for type 'UsersApp.MainWindow' that satisfies the specified binding constraints resulted in an exception being thrown.': line number '8' and line position '9'..
Source=PresentationFramework
StackTrace:
at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri) in System.Windows.Markup\XamlReader.cs:line 405

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(bool)
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(string)

Inner Exception 1:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Inner Exception 2:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize

Inner Exception 3:
ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section system.data. (C:\Users\nikit\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\University\University_KHPI_secondyear_2-1\C#_General\C#_Youtube_Course_Projects\C#_WPF\WPF-in-VisualStudio2022\UsersApp\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows\UsersApp.dll.config line 26)

`

[image: Here's the screenshot of the ReaderXaml.cs file that opens every time the program executes.]

Additionally, here are sections of the project that might be causing this exception:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window x:Class="UsersApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UsersApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        Title="Application for users" Height="600" Width="800">
        <Grid Background="#ffdadada">
            <Border MinWidth="400" Margin="15" Background="white" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="30" MaxWidth="550" CornerRadius="20">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="30" Color="LightGray" ShadowDepth="0" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="Hello you!" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 0 20" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="exampleText"  FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 0 0 20" />
                
                    <Grid Margin = "0 0 0 20">
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Registration" />
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Log in" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxLogin" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Enter login" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" />
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="passBox" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Enter password" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}"/>
                    <PasswordBox x:Name="passBox_2" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Repeat password" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintPasswordBox}" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBoxEmail" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Email" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" />
                    <Button Content="Register now!" Margin="0 20 " Click="Button_Rag_Click" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace UsersApp
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext();


            public MainWindow()
            {
            
                InitializeComponent();

                List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
                string str = "";
                foreach (User user in users)
                {
                    str += "Login: " + user.Login + " | ";
                }

                exampleText.Text = str;
            }

            private void Button_Rag_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                string login = textBoxLogin.Text.Trim(); //deleting spaces
                string pass = passBox.Password.Trim();
                string pass_2 = passBox_2.Password.Trim();
                string email = textBoxEmail.Text.Trim().ToLower();
    
                if (login.Length < 5)
                {
                    textBoxLogin.ToolTip = "This line is incorrect!";
                    textBoxLogin.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
                } else if (pass.Length < 5)
                {
                    passBox.ToolTip = "This line is incorrect!";
                    passBox.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
                } else if (pass != pass_2)
                {
                    passBox_2.ToolTip = "This line is incorrect!";
                    passBox_2.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
                } else if (email.Length < 5 || !email.Contains("@") || !email.Contains("."))
                {
                    textBoxEmail.ToolTip = "This line is incorrect!";
                    textBoxEmail.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
                } else
                {
                    textBoxLogin.ToolTip = "";
                    textBoxLogin.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    passBox.ToolTip = "";
                    passBox.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    passBox_2.ToolTip = "";
                    passBox_2.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                    textBoxEmail.ToolTip = "";
                    textBoxEmail.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

                    MessageBox.Show("Excellent!");
                    User user = new User(login, email, pass);
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

User.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace UsersApp
    {
        internal class User
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            private string login, email, pass;

            public string Login
            {
                get { return login; }
                set { login = value; }
            }

            public string Email
            {
                get { return email; }
                set { email = value; }
            }

            public string Pass
            {
                get { return pass; }
                set { pass = value; }
            }

            public User() { }

            public User(string login, string email, string pass)
            {
                this.login = login;
                this.email = email;
                this.pass = pass;
            }

        }
    }
```

App.xaml:

```
        <Application x:Class="UsersApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UsersApp"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
```

UsersApp.dll.config:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <!-- Если не работает, то сделайте следующее. Замените все содержимое файла, но объект startup установите такой же, как был у вас ранее  -->
      <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
      </startup>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\itproger.db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"  type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
          <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
        </providers>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
          <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
      </system.data>
    </configuration>
```

ApplicationContext.cs:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace UsersApp
    {
        // С помощью этого класса мы сможем
        // подключаться с необходимой базой данных
        internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    
            public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
        }
    }
```

For instance, here is a screenshot of SolutionExplorer:
[image: Solution Explorer list]

I've attempted to wrap suspicious methods within try/catch structures, particularly related to the database variable. Additionally, I've double-checked the correctness of the paths in the configuration file for the database and the "<system.data>" tags.

My expectation was to resolve the XamlParse Exception, allowing the program to register users and send data to the SQLite database.